# Query not calculating total Sum of Invoice_Total Column

Tags: mysql, sql

[I want to calculate the total sum of Invoice_Total as one Sum, not per row.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUKjF.jpg)

`SELECT YEAR(Invoice_Date)as SalesYear, MONTH(Invoice_Date)as SalesMonth, Client_Name,Invoice_Total, SUM(Invoice_Total) AS TotalSales FROM INVOICE
JOIN CLIENT
ON CLIENT.Client_ID= INVOICE.Client_ID
WHERE Invoice_Date between '2016-01-01'and'2016-01-31'
GROUP BY Client_Name, Invoice_Date, Invoice_Total;`

Comment: You should lookup "How to ask a question" on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *just* want `SUM` as one row then you can remove `GROUP BY` from query, e.g. it can be as simple as:

```
SELECT SUM(Invoice_Total)
FROM INVOICE
WHERE Invoice_Date BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-31';
```

**Update**

If you want the `SUM` of Invoice_Total from the existing query (along with the other columns) then you can wrap it into another query, e.g.:

```
SELECT SalesYear, SalesMonth, Client_Name, Invoice_Total, SUM(TotalSales) 
FROM (
 SELECT YEAR(Invoice_Date)as SalesYear, MONTH(Invoice_Date)as SalesMonth,   Client_Name,Invoice_Total, SUM(Invoice_Total) AS TotalSales FROM INVOICE
 JOIN CLIENT
 ON CLIENT.Client_ID= INVOICE.Client_ID
 WHERE Invoice_Date between '2016-01-01'and'2016-01-31'
 GROUP BY Client_Name, Invoice_Date, Invoice_Total
) a;
```

If you do not want other columns (as it won't make much sense to print the same value with all the rows), just use `SELECT SUM(TotalSales) FROM...`

Comment: I don't want the SUM as one row, I want to calculate the SUM of all Client's Invoice Total.                                                                                       And ok  I have edited the question,still new to this.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: I tried the updated query and got this error                                      
`ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias`

Comment: Ah okay. Sorry, updated the answer again. Just add `a` after the last closing bracket.

Comment: Thank you it got the total sum of invoice, but is there any way I show the other fields like from the screenshot  and still have the total sum of Invoice total

Comment: Updated the answer again (i.e. add those columns in `SELECT`). However, it won't make much sense as it will print the same `SUM` with all the rows.

Comment: Thank you so much, you've been so helpful and yea you're right I'll use the previous query you sent.

Comment: I have updated this info into my answer. Also, I'd appreciate if you could mark it as accepted if you think it has helped you.